# cannot access js code in content page

Tags: asp.net

I took one masterpage and one web form selected with the first master page. 
 
In this webform i took textbox and button. Button's OnClientClick property set with validate() 
I took one JScript.js file in that i write the following function :

`function validate() { 
    var no = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value;
    if (isNaN(no)) {
        alert('not a number.');
    }
}`

In default.aspx page i write the textbox and button code is as following 

`<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" onclientclick="validate()" Text="Button" />`

In master page's head section i call the js file as following :
`<script src="JScript.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>`

So the my question is this is not worked the alert message not appears as i write non numeric number in textbox.

Comment: If you don't already, try using the developer tools in Chrome. You can call js functions there in the console. Its useful for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use asp .net binding syntax in js files.

this will be rendered the same in your js file, and will not contain ur TextBox1ClientId:

```
var no = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value;
```

either pass the client Id from your aspx page as a parameter to the validate method, or embed your javascript function in ur aspx.

Comment: Thanks.. how to pass the client Id from your aspx page as a parameter to validate method.

Comment: try this: <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" onclientclick="validate('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>')" Text="Button" />

Comment: thanks... But please tell me that in the validate function what argument pass so that TextBox1.ClientID catch in that function

Comment: function validate(textboxId) { 
    var no = document.getElementById(textboxId).value;
    if (isNaN(no)) {
        alert('not a number.');
    }
}

Comment: In content page code : `<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`          `<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
        onclientclick="validate('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>')" Text="Button" />`                                             JScript.js code :                                       `function validate(TextBox1) {
    var no = document.getElementById(TextBox1).value;
    if (isNaN(no)) {
        alert('not a number.');
    }
}`                             It not works..

Comment: Well I can't do your work for you, check how your html looks on the browser, use chrome/firefox/IE debugging tools and see what's the problem. My personal guess is that server tags wont get bound in the tag definition, try to set a javascript variable in the page and pass it to ur validate function.

Answer (score 0):

You can add clientIDMode="Static" in your control.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" clientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" clientIDMode="Static" onclick="Button1_Click" onclientclick="validate()" Text="Button" />
```

Or if you want to make it project level, just add the line in web config file

```
<pages clientIDMode="Static"></pages>
```

inside `<system.web>`.